# AppleScript: Put text in Terminal ONLY (no execution)

Tags: terminal, applescript

I am using AppleScript to launch a certain python script. This python script uses arguments. I know how to use `do script` to launch commands but this time I just want to have `python myscript.py` ready. After that I would type my own argument and hit RETURN.

I don't know how to put the text in Terminal. Arguments will be different everytime I want to use the script, otherwise I would just use `do script`.

Answer (score 1):

This will type your command into the current active terminal window:

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "python myscript.py "
```

If you need to select which terminal window, then there will be a bit more work to do.